# Oracle UTL_FILE - multiple rows in excel for a single cell

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, utl-file

I have a requirement to display the below in a csv file which is generated using UTL_FILE package of PL/SQL.

Heading1      Heading2        Heading3
ABCDE         123             987641213
              xxx street
              yyyy

For each value in 'Heading1', I get 3 rows for address from a particular table.
In the output csv file, I need to display the address in a single cell with data separated by a new line.

I tried using a cursor and appending data using chr(10), chr(12), chr(15) but in vain.

Kindly help me in getting the output.

Answer (score 1):

you have to quote your field that has carriage returnseg

```
heading1,headiing2,heading3
abcde,123,"1 street
town
90210"
abcde,124,"13 street
town
43245"
```

Comment: Hi Dazzal,
I tried using carriage return ASCII value. I am writing the UTL_FILE output to a csv file with comma separated list. But I am getting these particular carriage returns as special character like boxes between each line. Also they are displayed on the same line.

Comment: what character sequence are you using for carriage return? it should be chr(13)||chr(10).

Answer (score 0):

What DazzaL proposed should work but if you can't change the input file in your case you can use this code :

```
declare
    v_line varchar2(2000);
    v_c1   varchar2(10);
    v_c2   varchar2(10);
    v_c3   varchar2(1980);
    nb_line_per_record integer := 3;
    v_line_in_record   integer;
    v_seperator varchar2(1) := ',';
    v_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
    v_file := utl_file.FOPEN(your_directory, 'your_file','r');
    v_line_in_record := 0;
    --we skip the first line
    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_file, v_line);
    loop
        v_line_in_record := v_line_in_record + 1; 
        begin
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_file, v_line);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                exit;
        END;
        --first line of record we cut by v_seperator
        if v_line_in_record = 1 then
           v_c1 := substr(v_line,1,instr(v_line,v_seperator,1,1)-1);
           v_c2 := substr(v_line,instr(v_line,v_seperator,1,1)+1,
                          instr(v_line,v_seperator,1,2)-                                
                          instr(v_line,v_seperator,1,1)-1);
           v_c3 := substr(v_line,instr(v_line,v_seperator,1,2)+1) 
                          || char(10);--if you want new line in adresse 
        else
            --not first line we concatanate to adress with new line
            v_c3 := v_c3 || v_line ||
                    case when v_line_in_record = 2 then char(10) else '' end; 
        end if;
        if v_line_in_record = 3 then
            v_line_in_record := 0;
            --do something with your record 
            insert into yourtable values (v_c1,v_c2,v_c3);
        end if;
    end loop;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    COMMIT;
end;
```

But this would work only if you are absolutely certain that every record is 3 lines. If i were you i would add a record delimiter after each record and use [SQLLOADER](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) to load this file into a table. You can define a Record delimiter with SQLLOADER.Here is an exemple ctl which uses & as record delimiter

> ```
> options (skip=1) 
>   load data 
>   infile "yourfile" "str '&'" 
>   truncate into table your_table 
>   fields terminated by "," 
>   trailing nullcols 
>   (heading1, heading2, heading3)
> ```

And if you use a Record delimiter you can even create an [External Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) on your file.

Comment: Hi Bulent,
Thanks for your wonderful query. But the problem is char(10) would make the 2nd row of the 3row output to be displayed in the next line of excel... I need those 3 rows to be displayed something like how we would use ALT+ENTER in excel to enter multiple lines of data within a single cell....

Basically, it should be 
<row1> ALT+ENTER
<row2> ALT+ENTER
<row3>

This would allow all data to appear in a single cell.